# Analytical solution for a nonlinear coupled PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I would like to find the solution to this nonlinearly coupled PDE:

[image]

This is an equation involving quantum mechanics and found in [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.84.1419). (Technically these E's are operators, but you can simply treat them as functions of z and t. Also $E^+$ is the conjugate of E so $E^+E = E^2 = E(z, t)^2$)

According to this paper, with some approximations, this has an analytical solution of the form $$E_{1,2}(z, t) = E_{1,2}(0,t') \exp(i \eta z |E_{2,1}(0, t')|^2)$$ where $t' = t-z/v_g$

If I am reading the paper correctly, the approximations are that $\beta \to 0$ and $F \to 0$ - but I'm not entirely sure. In my attempts to find the solution, I first tried to solve it as an ode (where the time derivatives are zero).

$$ E_1'(z) = -k E_1(z) + (i \eta)|E_2|^2 E_1 $$
$$ E_2'(z) = -k E_2(z) + (i \eta)|E_1|^2 E_2 $$
But I'm struggling to even work this out. Any ideas for how I can proceed?

EDIT:
One of the answers suggests a method at arriving at the solution, and here I'm showing my handwritten attempt at getting a solution using this method. I was successful in finding a solution (maybe with mistakes?) but ended up with an answer that does not match what is described in the text.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward procedure to arrive at the stated result is:

a) Change to comoving coordinates, i.e. write $E_{1,2}(z,t) = \tilde{E}_{1,2}(z,t')$ with $t'=t-z/v_g$;

b) Write the complex functions $\tilde{E}_{1,2}$ in terms of modulus and argument, i.e. write $\tilde{E}_{1,2}(z,t') = r_{1,2}(z,t')\, e^{i\, \omega_{1,2}(z,t')}$, where $r_{1,2}$ and $\omega_{1,2}$ are real-valued;

c) Substitute this into the equations and set $F_{1,2} = 0$ and $\beta = 0$;

d) Separate the real and imaginary parts in each equation, such that your equations are of the form $A + B i = 0$, $C + D i = 0$.

e) Solve the four equations $A = 0$, $B = 0$, $C = 0$, $D = 0$ for the four functions $r_{1,2}$ and $\omega_{1,2}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've found a solution to the PDE using your method, but it does not appear to resemble the solution given in the paper. I'll link a picture of my notes (or I can type it up and put it in the question if that's easier for you).

Comment: (I put a screenshot of my notes in the edit of the origional question)

Comment: You made a slight mistake in solving for $r_{1,2}$, there's a free function of $z$ (constant in $t$) $c_{1,2}(z)$ missing -- so, you should have written $r_{1,2}(z,t) = c_{1,2}(z) e^{-k t}$. Then, when you realise that $|E_{1,2}| = r_{1,2}$, the solution starts to take the shape of that in the paper. Your solution of $\omega_{1,2}$ has the same problem. Realise that the differential equations (first order, linear) you solve are for the variable $t$, and the functions $r$ and $\omega$ are functions of both $z$ and $t$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll go through and it again and check that it works.